# Etymology of Slovene vrtnica "rose". Can it be the Slavic reflex of PIE *wr̥dʰos “sweetbriar”?

Tags: etymology, indo-european, sound-change, slavic-languages, slovenian

Slovene has a word: *vrtnica* (wiktionary: [en](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vrtnica), [sl](https://sl.wiktionary.org/wiki/vrtnica)) meaning "rose".

It resembles the known Proto-Indo-European `*wr̥dʰos` “sweetbriar”, which gives  Persian *gul* "rose, flower" and Old/Middle Iranian borrowings including Old Armenian *vard* "rose" and Ancient Greek ῥόδον (*rhódon*, "rose") (to name the most well-known reflexes).
(See, for example, the StarLing database entry [`*wordh-, *word-`](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=/data/ie/piet&text_number=1180&root=config) or Wiktionary's [etymology for *rose*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rose#Etymology_1).)

Can it be a Slavic reflex that survived from the Proto-Indo-European root? Or the historical sound laws would give a different appearance of the root in Slavic?

Note that the StarLing database entry `*wordh-, *word-` or other etymological notes don't know any Slavic reflexes. To my knowledge, it is also not knwon in other Slavic languages, but Slovene.

If this could be a valid reflex of the Proto-Indo-European root according to the established historical sound laws, then it would be an interesting finding for Indo-European studies corroborating this reconstructed PIE root by the data from one more IE branch. Now the data from different branches is a bit scarce: taking into account that the Armenian form (and possibly the Greek one, too) is considered to be a borrowing, this reconstruction has a support from only two branches.

#### Appendix

The StarLing database entry [`*wordh-, *word-`](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?single=1&basename=/data/ie/piet&text_number=1180&root=config):

```
Proto-IE: *wordh-, *word-

Meaning: sweetbrier

Avestan: { varǝδa- `rose' }

Other Iranian: NPers gul `Rose' (< *wrdho-, cf. Arm vard < Iran)

Old Greek: rhódo-n, äol. bródo-n n. `Rose'

Germanic: *wurɵ=, *wurd=
 
  Proto-Germanic: *wurɵ=, *wurd=

  Meaning: a bush

  Norwegian: ol, dial. erre, orr (pl. errer), ordre

  Swedish: dial. orr, arre, arder

  Old English: { word `Dornstrauch' }

Russ. meaning: дерево (шиповник)

References: WP I 316
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(A long time after I wondered about this at Wiktionary discussion page, user  [Conlibae M. Rep](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Conlibae_M._Rep) knowledgable in Slovene gave an answer [there](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:rose#Etymology) that must settle this question! Let me translate from Russian [a similar answer](https://lev-m.livejournal.com/82602.html?thread=1217962#t1217962) another person (todash_tahken) gave in LiveJournal concerning this matter, which I've just found by googling.)

Those who know Slovene would understand without hesitation where the word *vrtnica* "rose" comes from.

- Slovene *vrt* ([wikt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vrt#Slovene)) means "garden".
- *vrtnica* stands for *vrtna roža*, literally "garden flower" ([wikt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ro%C5%BEa#Slovene)). (That's called *univerbisation*, when a single word is formed to stand for a whole combination of words.)

*vrtna roža* "garden flower" is calqued from German *Gartenrose*.  It appeared in Slovene in the 18th century.

---

Note that this word for "garden" is also present in Serbo-Croatian: *vȑt* (Cyrillic spelling вр̏т) ([wikt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vrt#Serbo-Croatian)); the etymology of the Slovene and Serbo-Croatian words being listed in Wiktionary is:

> From Proto-Slavic `*vъrtъ`, from Latin [*hortus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hortus#Latin).

Comment: FYI: Hieronymus Megiser 1592 Dictionarium quatuor linguarum already lists *roshni vert* "Rosengarten"; DWB mentions; Grimm's DWB later lists five senses for *R.* next to dimin. *Rosengärtchen* specifically noting "in österr. Schlesien" (Austrian Silesia; similarly Slovene in Megiser is called "Illyricae" in the subtitle and "Windisch" in the page headers, cp *the Wends*?) "nennt man einen wenig gebrauchten garten ein rosengärtchen" (one calls a little used garden a r.). long story short, I'd compare En *ward* and many cognates under the root \*wer-, glossed diversely, at least once "hill"

Comment: @vectory Thanks for interesting information! Do I understand correctly that your remark (1) shows that a combination of words *roža* and *vrt* was used in Slovene already before 18 c. (although that was a different composition, with the head "garden"; (2) suggests an alternative etymology for Slovene *vrt* "garden" instead of a borrowing from Latin. ((1) is quite clear; (2) is less obvious for me whether I've understood the intention of your remark concerning En. *ward* correctly.)

Comment: 1. Indeed, and I suggest compare Ger *Primel* "primrose", that is almost synonymous with *garden-variety*. 2. It's not obvious too me either. It's just a reminder to myself, as long as I can't figure it out. In short, [this fella here](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/en614k/how_breasts_became_browsers/) brought up a sense "to bud, sprout", I thought way to long about rosebuds (because of your post), breast warts (see there), and *Warzenhof*, so I imagined a hill, but when I saw \*wer- "highlands, hill" mentioned at Latin *varus* "pimpel" [Wikt] as predicted, I finally lost my mind.

Comment: @vectory As for (2), I'm not good at deciding which etymology is better. I prefer just to cite other specialists when I have to deal with eymology. And ask myself and others (as I did in this question):which outcome would the established laws of historical sound changes predict? As a way to verify the suggested derivation from a proto-form to a reflex.

Comment: This answer doesn't cover the part of the question which asks what the historical sound changes in Slavic would give for PIE *wrdhos. Still I'm accepting this as an answer as the provided etymology clearly rejects a connection with PIE `*wrdhos`.